# Azure Data Factory - Copy Data Timeout using XML Source

Tags: xml, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm getting timeout errors when I try to get mappings or preview data using ADF copy data. I have confirmed I'm able to view the data directly with my browser as XML, or download the data as a CSV if I change the http endpoint. The data itself is around ~120k rows at around 55MB.

Additional Information:

I've played around with the request timeout, but no matter what I set it to, it just errors after ~5 min.

I've tried changing the source to CSV, but get an error on the comma delimiter messing up the row count (This was originally working for months as XML, so figured XML is the right option again).
[image]

[image]

[image]

Thoughts on things to try? Kinda running out of ideas.

Thank you!

Comment: Could you please provide linked service details of xml dataset?

Comment: Could you please provide the error while importing the schema?

Answer (score 0):

After much fiddling, I was able to get this working by manually mapping in the schema. The pipeline eventually started running, but I was still getting timeout errors when attempting to import the schema. After manually typing each column and mapping it to my SQL Server, it finally ran through and formatted correctly.

[image]